# Convert list to nested lists and dicts

Tags: python

I have a set of data that looks similar to this:

```
[  {"name":"item.key" , "value":"value"},
   {"name":"item.key2" , "value":"value2"},
   {"name":"item.list.0" , "value":"listValue1"},
   {"name":"item.list.1" , "value":"listValue2"},
   {"name":"item.list.2" , "value":"listValue3"},·
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key1" , "value":"list2Key1Value"},
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key2" , "value":"list2Key2Value"},
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key3" , "value":"list2Key3Value"},·
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key1" , "value":"list3Key1Value"},
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key2" , "value":"list3Key2Value"},
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key3" , "value":"list3Key3Value"},
   {"name":"other.key" , "value":"otherKeyValue"}
]
```

The names were flattened from nested data containing lists and dicts.  I now want to unflatten it back into dicts and lists (where appropriate).

So far I have this:

```
obj = {}
def addObj(o, path, value):
    if len(path) > 1:
        o = o.setdefault(path.pop(0), {})
        addObj(o, path, value)
    else:
        o[path.pop(0)] = value

for item in data:
    parts = item['name'].split(".")
    addObj(obj, parts, item['value'])
```

Which will generate this:

```
{'item': {
     'key': 'value',
     'key2': 'value2',
     'list': {
         '0': 'listValue1',
         '1': 'listValue2',
         '2': 'listValue3'},
     'list2': {
         '0': {
             'key1': 'list2Key1Value',
             'key2': 'list2Key2Value',
             'key3': 'list2Key3Value'}
     },
     'list3': {
         '0': {
             'key1': 'list3Key1Value',
             'key2': 'list3Key2Value',
             'key3': 'list3Key3Value'}
     }
 },
 'other': {'key': 'otherKeyValue'}
}
```

But now, I want any dict that has keys that can all be cast as ints to be converted to lists, so my final output would look more like:

```
{'item': {
     'key': 'value',
     'key2': 'value2',
     'list': [
         'listValue1',
         'listValue2',
         'listValue3'],
     'list2': [{'key1': 'list2Key1Value',
             'key2': 'list2Key2Value',
             'key3': 'list2Key3Value'}],
     'list3': [{'key1': 'list3Key1Value',
             'key2': 'list3Key2Value',
             'key3': 'list3Key3Value'}]
 },
 'other': {'key': 'otherKeyValue'}
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just keep the original data around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but...

```
import pprint

data = [{"name":"item.key" , "value":"value"},
   {"name":"item.key2" , "value":"value2"},
   {"name":"item.list.0" , "value":"listValue1"},
   {"name":"item.list.1" , "value":"listValue2"},
   {"name":"item.list.2" , "value":"listValue3"},
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key1" , "value":"list2Key1Value"},
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key2" , "value":"list2Key2Value"},
   {"name":"item.list2.0.key3" , "value":"list2Key3Value"},
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key1" , "value":"list3Key1Value"},
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key2" , "value":"list3Key2Value"},
   {"name":"item.list3.0.key3" , "value":"list3Key3Value"},
   {"name":"other.key" , "value":"otherKeyValue"}]

obj = {}
def addObj(o, path, value):
    if len(path) > 1:
        o = o.setdefault(path.pop(0), {})
        addObj(o, path, value)
    else:
        o[path.pop(0)] = value

for item in data:
    parts = item['name'].split(".")
    addObj(obj, parts, item['value'])

# this function assumes all keys are strings
def convert(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if all(key.isdigit() for key in obj.keys()):
            return [convert(obj[key])
                    for key in sorted(obj.keys(), key=int)]
        return dict((key, convert(value)) for key, value in obj.items())
    return obj

pprint.pprint(convert(obj))
```

Which generates the following ouput:

```
{'item': {'key': 'value',
          'key2': 'value2',
          'list': ['listValue1', 'listValue2', 'listValue3'],
          'list2': [{'key1': 'list2Key1Value',
                     'key2': 'list2Key2Value',
                     'key3': 'list2Key3Value'}],
          'list3': [{'key1': 'list3Key1Value',
                     'key2': 'list3Key2Value',
                     'key3': 'list3Key3Value'}]},
 'other': {'key': 'otherKeyValue'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the genexp to better fit your needs (it may not be your real data), but that will work:

```
for v in d.values():
    for key in (i for i in v if i.startswith('list')):
        v[key] = list(v[key].values())
```

now the `d` dictionary has the content you want

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively walk through all dictionaries, and check if all keys can be converted to integers using this:

```
map(int, your_dict.keys())
```

This will generate a `ValueError` if one of the keys cannot be converted to `int`.

Note that this will not check whether the keys are consecutive integers nor whether they start at 0, so you might waste a lot of space when you convert the dictionary to a list.

Answer (score 0):

this is an incomplete implementation, just to demonstrate the idea:

`class A:
    def __init__(self, h):
        self.h = dict(zip(map(int, h.keys()), h.values()))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.h.get(i)`

then you can use this type to represent lists.